# Tracking wins & losses with PSQL/DataMapper

Tags: ruby, oop, sinatra, datamapper

I have a User class which allows people to register and play a game; I also have a Game class, which contains the logic of said game (RPS).

When people register, their information is held in a psql database. The informations is obtained using params. It looks like this:

```
Class User

  attr_reader :weapon

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,      Serial
  property :name,    String, required: true
  property :email,   String, required: true, unique: true
  property :password_digest, Text
  attr_reader :password
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_format_of :email, as: :email_address

  has n, :games
```

The corresponding Game class, contains this DB logic:

```
class Game

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,     Serial
  property :win,    ?
  property :lose,   ?

  belongs_to :user
```

My issue is that I really don't know how to keep a record of how many games the user has won/lost. Do I need (or should I have separate classes for wins and losses? What key type should I use (serial/int)? All I want is for 'win' or 'lose' to increment by one each time the player...well, wins or loses.

All help/knowledge shared is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be to add two integer columsn "wins" and "losses" to User, and make helper methods to increment:

```
property :wins, Integer, default: 0
property :losses, Integer, default: 0

# usage: user.increment(:wins) or user.increment(:losses)
def increment(type)
  update({ type => (send(:type) + 1) })
end
```